# Can you DROP TABLE IF EXISTS by specifying database name with table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-drop

I am trying to drop a table in a database with the following query statement:

```
mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "dbName.tableName"') or die(mysql_error());
```

But I keep getting an error. Does anyone know if specifying the dbName.tableName is invalid?

Comment: What is the error? Do u have permissiong to drop that table?

Comment: I assume you need to switch the double and single quotes. But I'd like to see the error.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"dbName.tableName"' at line 1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dbName`.`tableName`') or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: ok...I'l try -- so essentially you are stating the double-quotes will not work...I'll pots back in a moment

Comment: Wow..did not know that in certain mysql_queries -- double-quotes are not liked. Thanks @Emmerman!

Comment: It's not only about double quotes - you should quote db name _separapely_ from table name.

Comment: Yea, I saw that -- and again, did not know that as well.

Comment: Voted here and marked as answer because @Emmerman posted first

Answer (score 6):

You should use backticks instead of double quotes like this:

```
mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dbName`.`tableName`');
```

Comment: There where two problems with your original code. First, you should quote the dbName and tableName separately. Second, you only use single- or double quotes for strings. For identifiers, like table and column names, you use the backtick: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 3):

You can't use double quotes to quote db/table names, instead you either leave them unquoted or use backticks. But to answer your question, yes it is perfectly valid to specify the database name.

```
DROP TABLE `dbName`.`tableName`
```