# Drop Table if exists statement giving error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have following block of code in MySql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account.info`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `account.info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `year_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `school_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`account_id`,`year_id`,`school_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7177 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Its giving me error on first line as:

```
ERROR 1103 (42000) at line 56: Incorrect table name 'account.info'
```

What is wrong in it?

Please help me.

Comment: probably the ` Try to do a select statement on that table.

Comment: I think you just have your syntax slightly out. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046474/can-you-drop-table-if-exists-by-specifying-database-name-with-table) `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'account'.'info' the dbname and table name are in separate quotes.

Comment: why do you bother with if the table exists or not. just run the `DROP` statement catch the error. Then create. either way you get your result...

Comment: @LOLSinger: It seems you need a `account_info` table in your database but not an `info` table in `account` database.

Comment: @LOLSinger: Replace `account.info` with `account_info` and it should be working.

Comment: Same error for PDO $this->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " . $this->quote($table));

Answer (score 5):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html:
"Before MySQL 5.1.6, database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not permitted in file names."

Which is why I gave this answer:

You can't use dots in table names.  Dots are used to separate database names and table names (and column names).  You could try using `` `account`.`info` `` if your database name is `account` and the table name is `info`.  If the table name is supposed to be `account.info`, you should change that to something else, like `account_info`.  I don't agree with some of the other answers: Quoting never hurts, if done properly.

Since 5.1.6 you can use whatever you please, as shown by @eggyal and others.

Comment: @eggyal Older versions of MySQL don't permit this. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 3):

As documented under [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html):

> Before MySQL 5.1.6, database and table names cannot contain “`/`”, “`\`”, “`.`”, or characters that are not permitted in file names.

Incidentally, had you wanted to create a table called `info` within a database called `account`, then note that as documented under [Identifier Qualifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifier-qualifiers.html):

> If any components of a multiple-part name require quoting, quote them individually rather than quoting the name as a whole. For example, write `` `my-table`.`my-column` ``, not `` `my-table.my-column` ``.

Comment: I dont have database name as account,, i want to create "account.info" table separately itself

Comment: @LOLSinger see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776123/mysql-dot-in-database-name

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account.info;
```

dont use ` when using dots.

Or quote both db name and table name

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`.`info`;
```

Comment: "*don't use `\`` when using dots*" - What if the database name is a reserved word, or if either of database/table names contain a character that requires quoting?

Comment: `account` and `info` are none of these! but then we should do ` db `  .  ` tbl ` :)

Comment: @eggyal you should never use reserved words for naming database objects ;)

Comment: i just said "should" :D

Comment: if the names is in another language, should someone use ` `.` ` ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to create and first drop a table in the database account with the name info. If so, do it like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`.`info`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `account`.`info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `year_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `school_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`account_id`,`year_id`,`school_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7177 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: here it gives me error on CREATE TABLE `account``info` that >>> ERROR 1049 (42000) at line 60: Unknown database 'account'

Comment: Then you don't have a database named account. You want to create a table named only "account.info"? Don't use a dot in the name.

Comment: He can of course do, it's just the **easiest** way of avoiding problems.

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying a table called `account.info` and not a table called `info` in the account `db`. Quote each part separately:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`.`info`;
```

If you are trying to make a table called `account.info` then older versions of MySQL wont allow a `.` in a table name.

Comment: here it gives me error on CREATE TABLE account``info that >>> ERROR 1049 (42000) at line 60: Unknown database 'account'

Comment: @LOLSinger Singer what is the table name and the database name for the table?

Comment: @LOLSinger See my update. You can't create a table with a `.` in it in some versions of MySQL. Consider changing to, say, `account_info`.